# Brace initialization of non trivial struct leads to unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++

In the attached snippet I would expect `:std::vector<C> d = { {} };` to lead to a compiler error as `B` cannot be default constructed. Then if there is no error, I would expect `d.size()` to be `1`. Is this a case of unexpected behaviour or am I missing something self-evident?

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct A {};

struct B {
    B( int ) {}
};

struct C {
    A a;
    B b;
};


int main() {
    ::std::vector<C> d = { {} }; //ok?!?!
    //::std::vector<C> d2 = { C() }; Error
    //C c; Error
    //d.push_back( {} ); Error
    //d.push_back( { {}, { 3 } } ); Ok

    return d.size(); // 0 instead of expected 1
}
```

Comment: Try this: https://cppinsights.io/s/00630fff

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> ::std::vector<C> d = { {} };
> ```

Is calling the 10th constructor at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector :

```
vector( std::initializer_list<T> init,
       const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

The inner `{}` is an empty `std::initializer_list`, and the outer `{   }` is [copy-list-initialization form 6](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Pro tip: with a properly configured IDE, you are able to "go to definition" of symbols. I placed my cursor on the first `{` and clicked "go to definition", and my IDE jumped to the proper vector constructor with initializer_list. Placing cursor on the second `{` and "go to definition", jumps to initializer_list constructor.

Comment: C++ Insights to prove: https://cppinsights.io/s/1694f608